# How can I filter databases by owner using psql?

Tags: psql

I know I can list my postgres databases with the following command:

```
# list only the databases
psql -U openerp -q -t -c "select datname from pg_database;" template1
```

Or

```
# show a full listing of databases
psql template1 -U openerp -l
```

How can I filter the databases by owner 'openerp'? `datdba` field is just a number... how can I map it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like this, you'll want to query `pg_database` directly. The `owner` field is a reference to `pg_catalog.pg_authid.oid`, but this is a superuser-only accessible table. There's a view, `pg_catalog.pg_roles` that exposes the id as the `oid` attribute, so you can:

```
select 
  datname,
  rolname AS dbowner
from pg_database d 
     inner join pg_roles r on (d.datdba = r.oid);
```

Comment: U're right. After digging for hours I found this approach (yes, i'm a pg n00b)

Comment: It works! I just added a `where` clause to filter by my desired rolname. `where rolname='ramy'` .